# Why does property spreading work inside Grid but not in FormControl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, material-ui

Sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-ardinghelli-fnoj15?file=/src/temp4.tsx:0-1206.

```
import { FormControl, FormControlProps, Grid, GridProps } from "@mui/material";

interface ICustomControlProps {
  gridProps?: GridProps;
  formControlProps?: FormControlProps;
}

const CustomControl = (props: ICustomControlProps) => {
  return (
    <Grid {...props.gridProps}>
      <FormControl {...props.formControlProps} />
    </Grid>
  );
};

const CustomControlVariant1 = (props: ICustomControlProps) => {
  return (
    <CustomControl
      /**
       * Below gridProps is of type GridProps.
       * It is set to object with some fixed (item, xs, sm, md) properties and spreaded props.gridProps 
       * (which is of type GridProps). 
       * But doing exactly same with formControlProps doesnt work: setting fixed component properties
       * and spreaded props.formControlProps
       */
      gridProps={{ item: true, xs: 12, sm: 12, md: 12, ...props.gridProps }}
      formControlProps={{
        component: "fieldset",  /** ERROR: Type '{ children?: React.ReactNode; classes?: Partial<FormControlClasses> & 
                                  * Partial<ClassNameMap<never>>; color?: "error" | ... 4 more ... | "warning"; ...
                                  * 264 more ...; component: string; }' is not assignable to type 'FormControlProps<"div", {}>'.
                                  * Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'component' does not exist in type 
                                  * 'FormControlProps<"div", {}>'. 
                                  * 
                                  * Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'component' 
                                  * does not exist in type 'FormControlProps<"div", {}>'.ts(2322)
                                  */
        ...props.formControlProps
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

**Update**

Note that adding another level of spreading for `FormControl` works:

```
<CustomControl
      gridProps={{ item: true, xs: 12, sm: 12, md: 12, ...props.gridProps }}

      // this works!! So, `component` is indeed on `FormControlProps`
      // which can be confirmed here: https://mui.com/api/form-control/#props
      formControlProps={{
        ...{
          component: "fieldset",
          ...props.formControlProps
        }
      }}
    />
```

Here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-ardinghelli-fnoj15?file=/src/temp5.tsx:429-685) for this code.

I find both approaches logically correct and in my opinion, both should work, but I don't understand why the first one is giving an error.

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR;

In order to make TypeScript happy, you could modify `ICustomControlProps` as follows:

```js
interface ICustomControlProps {
  gridProps?: GridProps;
  formControlProps?: FormControlProps & { component: React.ElementType };
}
```

---

### Explanation

Let's have a look in the `FormControl`'s declaration file:

```js
declare const FormControl: OverridableComponent<FormControlTypeMap>;

export type FormControlProps<
  D extends React.ElementType = FormControlTypeMap['defaultComponent'],
  P = {},
> = OverrideProps<FormControlTypeMap<P, D>, D>;
```

Concisely, `FormControlProps` will gather together the props of the **default component**(which is a `div` - so, some props a specific DOM element can take in) and the props which define the `FormControl` component(these can be found in `FormControlTypeMap`, e.g. `classes`, `fullWidth`, `hiddenLabel` etc).

In `FormControlTypeMap` there surely is no `component` property defined and hence the error. However, `OverridableComponent<FormControlTypeMap>` says that receiving a `component` prop is accepted:

```js
export interface OverridableComponent<M extends OverridableTypeMap> {
  <C extends React.ElementType>(
    props: {
      /**
       * The component used for the root node.
       * Either a string to use a HTML element or a component.
       */
      component: C;
    } & OverrideProps<M, C>,
  ): JSX.Element;
  (props: DefaultComponentProps<M>): JSX.Element;
}
```

So, you can *safely* use `FormControl` like this: `<FormControl component={...} />`, but wrapping it in another component, like this:

```js
interface ICustomControlProps {
  gridProps?: GridProps;
  formControlProps?: FormControlProps;
}

const CustomControl = (props: ICustomControlProps) => {
  return (
    <Grid {...props.gridProps}>
      <FormControl {...props.formControlProps} />
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

will require you to specify that a `component` prop is also allowed on `ICustomControlProps.formControlProps`:

```js
interface ICustomControlProps {
  gridProps?: GridProps;
  formControlProps?: FormControlProps & { component: React.ElementType };
}
```

---

As to why this works:

```
formControlProps={{
  ...{
    component: "fieldset",
    ...props.formControlProps
  }
}}
```

the answer seems to be found in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38657), more specifically [in this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38657#issuecomment-647566770), which says that `...` **creates a subtype**, so it's all valid.